# Terminal emulator supporting MC2

Tags: terminal, ncurses, legacy, terminal-emulator

The "Link MC2" hardware terminal of my client has went down.
These terminals are very old.
It is difficult to find one on the second hand market.
The host behind the terminal is critical to my client business and it does require a MC2 terminal for the user interface.

Do you know a software terminal emulator having MC2 emulation ?

Comment: The RS-232 logs indicates that the escape sequence for moving the cursor to an other line is 1b 6d (ESC m) and the escape sequence for moving the cursor to an other column is 1b 6e (ESC n)

Comment: You're unlikely to find an emulator for *Link MC2*.  It did happen to emulate a few other terminals (for which some emulators can be found).  A *Link MC5* might be compatible.

Comment: Thanks for your comment, Thomas. Thanks also for Invisible-island which is a great source of information. I had searched these escape sequences in the terminfo entries on your web site with no result. I had tested Link MC5 but it does not work. These 2 escape sequences seem to be the only ones to configure in order to be able to use the interface (plus maybe the 'clear screen' which is 1b 2b ESC +). I am now looking for a terminal emulator which can accept custom escape sequences, or alternatively developing a dedicated terminal emulator, maybe based on pyserial or similar.